# how to create a bootable flash that can boot as both BIOS and UEFI?

Tags: arch-linux, usb-drive, uefi, bios

I'm creating a bootable recovery flash and I was wondering how to create it so it can boot on both UEFI and BIOS systems?

I'm experimenting with GRUB but I'm open to any other bootloader.

Requirements:

1. being able to boot Linux from the stick.
2. being able to detect / chainload windows on the target computer (not creating a bootable win install).

Comment: What I use is a combination of syslinux's isolinux (for legacy BIOS) and grub (for EFI bootloader) and isohybrid (to make bootable iso image). This has been working well because I am able to not only support a hybrid iso that can boot in both legacy and UEFI but also boot on MAC hardware which uses a special type of EFI.

Comment: @likewhoa can you write that as a detailed answer by any chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found https://debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/112:

Copy/pasting here for longevity, all credit goes to the original author.

(I modifed the steps a little so the EFI partition is only 200mb and the rest of the flash has multiple ISOs and shared ntfs files):

```
parted /dev/sdX -- mktable gpt
parted /dev/sdX -- mkpart biosgrub fat32 1MiB 4MiB
parted /dev/sdX -- mkpart efi fat32 4MiB 200MiB
parted /dev/sdX -- set 1 bios_grub on
parted /dev/sdX -- set 2 esp on
mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n EFI /dev/sdX2

mkdir /tmp/new-boot && mount /dev/sdX2 /tmp/new-boot
grub-install --removable --no-nvram --efi-directory=/tmp/new-boot/ --boot-directory=/tmp/new-boot/ --target=x86_64-efi
grub-install --removable --no-nvram --efi-directory=/tmp/new-boot/ --boot-directory=/tmp/new-boot/ --target=i386-efi
grub-install --removable --boot-directory=/tmp/new-boot/ --target=i386-pc /dev/sdX
```

Comment: Not a good idea to try and have a single recovery media for both BIOS/MBR and UEFI/GPT.   For BIOS/MBR there are plenty of good rescue tools available.  For UEFI/GPT, see http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2014/12/creating-a-uefi-rescue-dvd.html for an early version of a rescue DVD that I developed.  Can be burned onto a USB stick.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 it's for my personal use and it works (tm), but all means please post some details and if your answer shows better information, I'll mark it.